# Node.js and Express.js create a large CSV file (1GB) and download it from ajax client

Tags: ajax, node.js, csv, express

The UI allows users to select a couple query parameters and submit via AJAX.
The server will query mongoDB with the parameters and create a very large CSV file (30 columns/1.5MM rows/~1GB) on the server.
Once the file is created, the server responds to the AJAX call with the URL to download the file.
A second call is made to the server to download the CSV file.

My problem is scaling this solution...  Node.js runs out of memory when trying to retrieve more than 50,0000 records from mongoDB.  System is running with 4GB memory.

AJAX call to create and download the file:

```
 handleExport: function (){
        NProgress.done();
        NProgress.start();
        var data = {spMle: this.state.spMle, custMle: this.state.custMle};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/aps/export',
            data: data,
            success: function (filename){
                NProgress.done();
                var url = '/api/aps/export/download/' + filename
                $('body').append("<iframe src='" + url + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
                //window.open(url);
            }
        });
    },
```

Server request to create the CSV file from the MongoDB query, and send the URL to download the file back to the client:

```
var spMle       = req.body.spMle;
var custMle     = req.body.custMle;
var limit       = 50000;
var filename    = 'export.csv';
var path        = './public/downloads/' + filename;
var query       = ApsModel.find();
if (spMle !== "0"){query.where('SP_MLE_ID').equals(spMle);}
if (custMle !== "0"){query.where('Cust_MLE_ID').equals(custMle);}
if (limit){query.limit(limit);}

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
writeStream.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('CSV file completed!');
    res.send(filename);
});
var readStream = query.stream({ transform: JSON.stringify});
var json2CsvStream = new Json2CsvStream();
json2CsvStream.on('header', function(data) {
  // console.log(' ++ yeah header found ++');
  // return console.log(data);
})
json2CsvStream.on('line', function(data) {
  console.log('row streamed');
  // return console.log(data);
});

readStream.pipe(json2CsvStream).pipe(writeStream);
```

Server request to download the file:

```
router.get('/aps/export/download/:filename', function (req, res){
    var path = './public/downloads/' + req.params.filename;
    res.download(path, "export.csv")
});
```

Comment: [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) will help here, MongoDB `QueryStream` --> csv formatting stream --> response stream

Comment: That worked well!  Forgot about querystream.  I updated the code above to include mongo streaming.

Comment: Awesome news, download file worked??

Comment: No, it didn't work for the 1MM file.  Waited about 25 mins then gave up.  It did work for 100K file, which took about a minute and a half to create and download.  What do you recommend instead of res.download?

Comment: Perhaps set a really long timeout in the `$.ajax()` call.  Also, you should pipe the entire thing to `res.download` (wasn't obvious if you did that from the code)

Comment: Followed your original suggestion to stream everything.  It can now generate/download a file with 250K rows in 3 mins.

Answer (score 3):

Refactored it into the following data flow using streams end-to-end:

1) Pipe mongo query
2) Pipe data to json-to-csv parser
3) Pipe parsed data to client

Jquery call:

```
handleExport: function (){
        var url ="/api/aps/export/" + this.state.spMle + "/" + this.state.custMle;
        $('body').append("<iframe src='" + url + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
        //window.open(url);
    },
```

Server response:

```
/* GET aps export */
router.get('/aps/export/:spMle/:custMle', function (req, res){
    var spMle       = req.params.spMle;
    var custMle     = req.params.custMle;
    var limit       = 250000;
    var filename    = 'export.csv';
    var query       = ApsModel.find();
    if (spMle !== "0"){query.where('SP_MLE_ID').equals(spMle);}
    if (custMle !== "0"){query.where('Cust_MLE_ID').equals(custMle);}
    if (limit){query.limit(limit);} 
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + filename
    }
    res.writeHead(200, headers)

    var mongoStream = query.stream({transform: JSON.stringify});
    var parser = new Json2CsvStream();

    //run streams
    mongoStream.pipe(parser).pipe(res)

});
```